# Sending Push Notifications using expo + firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-functions, expo

I am trying to send push notifications using expo tokens and firebase.
When I am trying to test the expo tokens by sending notification by expo notification tool it works fine.
But when I use firebase to check the push notification it does not works.
Here is my firebase function `index.js` file.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
var fetch = require('node-fetch')
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendPushNotification = functions.database.ref('/UserOrders/').onCreate((snap, context) => {
    const root = snap.data.ref.root

    var messages = []

    return root.child('/PushNotification').once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
            var expoToken = childSnapshot.val().expoToken;
            messages.push({
                "to": expoToken,
                "sound": "default",
                "body": "New enquiry. Please see!!"
            });
        });
        return Promise.all(messages)
    }).then(messages => {
        console.log('messages', messages)
        fetch('https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(messages)
        });
    }).catch(reason => {
        console.log('reason failure', reason)
    })
});
```

Comment: Check cloud function logs, if it is called or not, if there is any error or not

Comment: I'll answer my own question. In the new firebase updated version it's `snap.data.root`